# Lucene Index Document Numbers: Lookup and Store document number in existing Index

Tags: java, search, lucene

I have a Lucene index where each document has no unique searchable fields. Changing the index is out of the question. I am iterating over this index and each time I encounter a document that passes some test, I want to add a reference to that document to an arbitrary data structure.

Is there a native way to store the document number for a quick and reliable future lookup?
eg I encounter the 5th document, I want to store '5' and be able to lookup document 5 in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your index read-only, or does it get modified from time to time? If read-only, can you use the document number that Lucene assigns? If not read-only, can you add some unique value to each document the next time you modify the index?

Comment: if it's not read-only, realize that merges that happen automatically will rearrange the document #s. They are not meant to be used for permanent lookup purposes